# Page Displayed Blank using Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

i am creating simple spring boot application project. when i run the project ran into the problem with Spring Boot Page Displayed Blank . i have create two various controller those are student and course controller and Index controller is Index controller is a Main Page .
First Controller i need to display Index controller. but course controller is displayed as a first page with blank i don't know the reason why.
i attached full code at git hub link `https://github.com/raguram1986/SpringSecuritys`

**Course Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/course")

public class CourseController {
    
     @Autowired
        private CourseService service;

        @GetMapping("/")
        public String viewHomePage(Model model) {
            List<Course> listcourse = service.listAll();
            model.addAttribute("listcourse", listcourse);
            System.out.print("Get / "); 
            return "Course";
        }
```

**Index Controller**

```
    @Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class IndexController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public String index() {
          return "index";
       }
       @RequestMapping(value = "/student", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public String aboutus() {
          return "student";
       }

}
```

**Student Controller**

```
 @Controller
@RequestMapping("/Student")

public class StudentController {
    
     @Autowired
        private StudentService service;

        @GetMapping("/Student")
        public String viewHomePage(Model model) {
            List<Student> liststudent = service.listAll();
         //   model.addAttribute("liststudent", liststudent);
            System.out.print("Get / "); 
            return "Student";
        }}
```

Comment: Did you see any error in server console or browser console while navigating on the blank page?

Comment: no error displayed

Comment: i attached the full code at git hub.i gave the link above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have duplicate mappings for course and student, like:

```
@RequestMapping("/student")
```

And Index controller you have dublicate for /student:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class IndexController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public String index() {
          return "index";
       }
       **@RequestMapping(value = "/student"**, method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public String aboutus() {
          return "student";
       }
```

RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET) and @GetMapping are basicly same thing.

Comment: i modified the code what you said but same black page displayed see above i modified the code above

Comment: I do not remember how RequestMapping("/")   + RequestMapping("/index") going to show actually. You can test is it //index or do it remove extra "/" from address?

Comment: http://localhost:7090/index  i tested still black displayed

Comment: localhost:7090//index test that.